# mongodb module to use annotation for indexes

Tags: mongodb, module, playframework

From the doc provided, http://www.playframework.org/modules/mongo-1.3/home, I don't see such annotation available but it seems that the code need to be write to create/specify indexes. Is that still the case for now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Mongo only with Play, I think the right module is [play-morphia](http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia)
The one you chose is not quite active afaik!

*(FYI I'm currently working on the implementation of mongodb for [siena](http://www.sienaproject.com), a SQL/NoSQL framework tightly integrated with play using module [play-siena](http://www.playframework.org/modules/siena)... This mongo impl should be ready in a few weeks)*